# Tests using rspec, capybara and poltergeist return empty html and empty screenshots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

So I've been struggling with this for quite some time now and I can't seem to figure our what's going wrong, and couldn't find much on what could possibly cause this issue.

I'm relatively new to Ruby and Rails, as well as test/behavior driven development and am trying to write some acceptance (browser) tests using PhantomJS through Poltergeist, using Rspec and Capybara. I believe some people also call this integration tests (they may be from some perspective), but that's a whole other discussion.

I have a really simple feature that I can't get to do what I want:

```
require 'feature_helper'

feature 'Logging in', :js => true do

  scenario 'with incorrect credentials' do
    visit '/login'
    puts page.html
    save_and_open_page
    page.driver.render('_screenshot.png', :full => true)
    page.html.should have_selector("title", :text => "hi")
  end

end
```

So. Simple, right. It should just go to `/login` and throw the HTML content at me, as well I want to see the page using `save_and_open_page`, and I want it to take a screenshot. I added a simple `should have_selector` in order to have the test fail in an attempt to get more feedback.

The relative contents of my `feature_helper.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
include Capybara::DSL

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {
        :debug => true,
        :inspector => true
    })
end
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

FakeWeb.allow_net_connect = %r[^https?://(127.0.0.1|localhost)] # allow phantomjs/poltergeist requests

DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.before :each do
        # Set the hostname to something with test
        @host = "test.iome:3003"
        host! @host
        Capybara.default_host = Capybara.app_host = "http://#{@host}/"
        Capybara.server_port = 3003
        Capybara.reset_sessions!

        # Start the database cleaner
        config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
        DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after :each do
        DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
end
```

And also my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'pry'

require 'fakeweb'
FakeWeb.allow_net_connect = false
```

It's all fairly simple.

Now, in my console I see the following:

```
{"name"=>"visit", "args"=>["http://test.iome:3003//login"]}
{"response"=>{"status"=>"fail"}}
{"name"=>"body", "args"=>[]}
{"response"=>"<html><head></head><body></body></html>"}
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
{"name"=>"body", "args"=>[]}
{"response"=>"<html><head></head><body></body></html>"}
{"name"=>"render", "args"=>["_screenshot.png", true]}
{"response"=>true}
{"name"=>"body", "args"=>[]}
{"response"=>"<html><head></head><body></body></html>"}
```

Also, the screenshot is just a white and empty page. When I tail my `log/test.log` file, I don't see that a request is being performed. I've tried changing the method `visit` to `get`, and that'll make the request, but won't change any of the results.

I've completely run out of ideas of what this could be and it's rather frustrating :(

Final information then about versions:

- rspec 2.10.0
- capybara 1.1.4
- poltergeist 1.0.3
- ruby 1.8.7
- rails 3.2.13

Unfortunately we're still at ruby 1.8.7, but are working on bumping that version up. Still, I think this shouldn't influence the tests.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you just go to your browser and type in the URL (i.e. `http://test.iome:3003/`) do you get a response?

Comment: When I'm running the tests: yes. I seem to get a little bit more now though. It's a new day so new things are happening :) I believe the port used for the tests was still in use, causing the application to timeout at boot. It seemed that nginx was still running.

The `page.html` attribute also has content now. However, while a screenshot file was made but was blank before, it now doesn't create a file at all. Also, I add some information to the database required for login, but this information isn't available to the application. Will let you know of updates.

Comment: Can you add the code for your controller action? I'm experiencing the same issue and want to compare! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So eventually I got help from a colleague, and we managed to fix it. We used the `lvh.me` domain for this, as any request to that domain will resolve in localhost, allowing you to use subdomains without a problem. You could probably also use `hostname.127.0.0.1.xip.io` for this.

Our `spec_helper.rb` now looks like this:

```
# Use capybara in combination with poltergeist for integration tests
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'rack_session_access/capybara'
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.always_include_port = true
Capybara.app_host = 'http://application-test.lvh.me'  # Any lvh.me domain resolves to localhost
Capybara.default_wait_time = 8                        # How long capybara should look for html elements

require 'vcr'
VCR.configure do |config|
  config.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/vcr_cassettes'
  config.hook_into :fakeweb
  config.ignore_localhost = true
  config.configure_rspec_metadata!
  config.ignore_hosts 'codeclimate.com'
end

require 'fakeweb'
FakeWeb.allow_net_connect = false
```

Because we hooked in VCR to record any requests going out during the first run of the integration tests, all your integration tests, or features, should contain this code:

```
before(:all) do
  FakeWeb.allow_net_connect = true
end

after(:all) do
  FakeWeb.allow_net_connect = false
end
```

If you want to change the subdomain during your specs, you can use the following:

```
before(:each) do
  @original_host = Capybara.app_host
  Capybara.app_host = 'http://does-not-exist.lvh.me'
  visit '/login'
end

after(:each) do
  Capybara.app_host = @original_host
end
```

Making screenshots can now be done using `page.save_screenshot` during specs. Hope this helps.